# Halmos set definition of projection onto the first coordinate, notation confusion.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, self-learning

on page 24 of "Naive Set Theory" Halmos shows that:

> If $R$ is a set such that every element of $R$ is an ordered pair, then there exists two sets $A$ and $B$ such that $R ⊆ A x B$

then he calls the projection of $R$ onto the first coordinate as the set $A = \{a: \text{for some b }((a,b \in R))\}$ this doesn't make sense to me, shouldn't this set be defined as $\{a \in A : (a,b) \in R\}$ or are these just exactly the same set, just written differently?

Comment: If I'm following what's going on, then when you are trying to define the set $A$ it would be circular to use $A$ itself for defining itself. Therefore you can't write things as you did and you have to write it as Halmos did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define the set $A$ you don't "have" it yet (i.e. you haven't shown $A$ exists), so you cannot use comprehension over $A$ as you do. That's **circular**.

But Halmos works more naively and starts out from $R$ directly:

$A=\{a\mid \exists b : (a,b) \in R\}$, leaving it undetermined what sets $a$ and $b$ come from..

If you want to be fully formal (axiomatic), you *can* find a set of which $A$ is a subset (hint: union axiom and recall that $(a,b) = \{\{a\}, \{a,b\}\}$ if we follow Kuratowski, I don't recall if Halmos does this though..) and use comprehension from that. Or use axiom of replacement, maybe.

Comment: Im confused? Halmos already showed the set A exists and then after the proof as a remark says you can define the projection.

Comment: @JCAL how does he show that $A$ exists?

Comment: He lets A be equal to Union Union R

Comment: @JCAL I hint at that at the end. And then you can write $A=\{ a \in \bigcup \bigcup R \mid \exists b: (a,b) \in R\}$ for the projection.

Comment: Right but seem this is where I’m confused A = union union R

Comment: @JCAL $A$ need not be exactly $\bigcup \bigcup R$, $B$ is also a subset of that double union. $A$ and $B$ can be disjoint, e.g.  for $A$ you only want those elements that actually occur as the first component of a pair in $R$.

Comment: Okay, thank you for this.

Comment: @JCAL you’re welcome.